How do you fill a column with an alphabet series?

Given A to E in a column, how do I fill the rest of the letters up to R (or Y or Z etc) without typing them one by one? The blue dot handle doesn't seem to be able to do this, it just repeats the series. Holding shift or control doesn't work. This has probably been asked before, I just don't know what the correct term is.

Text strings will fill down to a series when they have a numeric suffix, but purely alphabetic strings will only repeat.
To get the series like A, B, C, ... Z, use a formula, like this:
=map(sequence(26), lambda(i, char(code("A") + i - 1)))

See How does fill-down work with text strings, numbers, dates and formulas?.

For a drag-and-fill solution if A is on Row 1 then you can use the following formula:
=CHAR(64+ROW())

If not, then use the following formula that subtracts 1 less than the row containing A.  For example,  if A is in cell A3 (row 3) then you'd subtract 2:
=CHAR(64+ROW()-2)

You can also calculate it using an absolute reference to the row containing A. It's basically the same calculation as above but dynamic. The cell reference is absolute so it doesn't shift as you fill the formnula down the column. For example, using the same example as above, where A is in A3:
=CHAR(64+ROW()-ROW($A$3)+1)

